# How to set up user 'tagging' with Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, tagging

I am currently making an app with Parse in which users can upload photos and other users can comment on the photos. I would like to set up a method by which a user can 'tag' another user in a comment, similar to facebook/instagram by typing @username.
I would like this to then send a notification to the mentioned user, but this can be done easily with Parse push notifications. How would i go about setting up the tag feature?

Answer (score 1):

Create a cloud `afterSave()` function that scans the comment for a user tag (@username). If found, query for the user(s). If username(s) match existing user(s), trigger notification(s).

This involves quite a lot of things to develop if you don't already support notifications. But my outline is *what* you need to do. *How* is something you need to try for yourself and then ask specific questions here on SO if you have problems.

Comment: This was my initial plan of how to do it, but it seems slow but the individual parts are not difficult to impliment. I was just wondering if there was a method that existed that would make this easier such as an API. But thank you for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement face recognition with OpenCV or natively, check  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

Comment: The tagging should come exclusively from the comments section, facial recognition is not needed. For example i can tag you as follows @OleksandrBretsko